# Configuring Spring Data error message

Tags: java, error-handling, spring-data, extract-error-message

Is it possible to configure spring data to return a generic error message instead of the specific SQL Error message?

I'm asking this because I need to change a system that is accessing a database and when throwing an error is "giving away" too many database information, eg: like database version.

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap the database query in a try statement and then in the catch section output a custom generic error message using a logger or otherwise.

You could further find out which exception it is in particular using the 'instanceof' comparitor.

Is this the answer you're looking for or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: I can do that one by one on each statement, but it'll take a lot of time. What I'm looking for is a simple way to handle all database exceptions and send back my generic error message.

Comment: If you abstract the controller away from the section(s) that are making the calls to the database you could call the method and catch it all at a higher level by adding the additional SQL exceptions to the 'throws' clauses.

Comment: That's a good idea but I'm looking for a single point of change that would affect all database calls.